# Do navigation databases (by e.g. Aeronavdata or Jeppesen) include company routes?

Tags: navigation, fms

Does the navigation database provided by database providers like Aeronavdata or Jeppesen etc include company routes?

1. How are the company routes maintained; are they modifiable by the OEMs?
2. Is the navigation database customizable?

Any insight on this will be helpful.

Comment: Helpful in what way?

Comment: By OEM do you mean the FMC manufacturer or the Database vendor?

Answer (score 2):

The company routes are maintained by your company.  Some FMS installations have a computer program where you can create the company routes and upload them to each FMS.  Other FMS requires each FMS to be programmed.

All FMS have the ability to see if the routes have been changed due to a database change.   If the pilots wanted to use those company routes the FMS would require them to verify the routes are stored correctly.